# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log

Tags: spring, maven, gwt

I am getting this error while deploying my application

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Ma
      rker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.info(SLF4JLocat
        ionAwareLog.java:141)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
        xt(ContextLoader.java:272)
```

I am using maven And This is my pom.xml

```
    <properties>
    <!-- Using this GWT version -->
    <gwt.version>2.4.0</gwt.version>

    <!-- Using this Jackrabbit version -->
    <jcr.version>1.6.5</jcr.version>

    <!-- Using this Spring version -->
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    <!-- Apache CXF -->
    <cxf.version>2.5.1</cxf.version>

    <!-- Apache POI -->
    <poi.version>3.8</poi.version>

    <!-- Milton WebDAV -->
    <milton.version>1.8.1.3</milton.version>

    <!-- Tell the compiler we can use 1.6 -->
    <java.compiler>1.6</java.compiler>

     <!-- Default source encoding ${default.encoding} -->
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     </properties>

    <repositories>
     <!-- Needed for org.jbpm & org.hibernate-->
    <repository>
      <id>jboss.org</id>
      <name>JBoss Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Needed for ROME -->
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Needed for Gson -->
    <repository>
      <id>gson</id>
      <name>GSon Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Needed for Milton -->
    <repository>
      <id>ettrema-repo</id>
      <name>Milto WebDAV</name>
      <url>http://milton.io/maven</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- OpenKM repository -->
    <repository>
      <id>openkm.com</id>
      <name>OpenKM Maven Reporitory</name>
      <url>http://maven.openkm.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- StringTree repository -->
    <repository>
      <id>StringTree</id>
      <name>String Tree</name>
      <url>http://stringtree.org/repository/</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- Video conversion and resolution change -->
    <repository>
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <name>Xuggle</name>
        <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Test units -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Provided libraries -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- JBoss already have its own log4j.jar -->
      <!-- http://www.coderanch.com/t/91054/JBoss/log-j-messages-JBoss-log -->
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
      <version>7.0.27</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Misc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.schlichtherle</groupId>
      <artifactId>truezip</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Base64 encoding / decoding -->
    <!-- http://www.techiegyan.com/?p=333 -->
    <!-- Downgraded to 1.3 due to GWT 2.2 dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackrabbit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jcr.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- We want to use the last POI version -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>

        <!-- Hibernate Search uses a more recent version of Lucene-->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
          <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackrabbit-text-extractors</artifactId>
      <version>${jcr.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>pdfbox</groupId>
          <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Twitter4j -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.homeip.yusuke</groupId>
      <artifactId>twitter4j</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ROME -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>rome</groupId>
      <artifactId>rome</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JasperReports -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.6</version>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Avoid java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler -->
        <!-- See http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/49e20fb5185b34ce/75436f95e29dce85?hl=en -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
          <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all-minimal</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Workflow library from JBoss -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm.jbpm3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-jpdl</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.OKM</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>bsh</groupId>
          <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jbpm.jbpm3</groupId>
      <artifactId>jbpm-identity</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1.OKM</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
          <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
      <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- BeanShell support -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
      <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OpenOffice.org integration -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.artofsolving.jodconverter</groupId>
      <artifactId>jodconverter-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0-beta-4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Text extractors -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>entagged.audioformats</groupId>
      <artifactId>audioformats</artifactId>
      <version>0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
      <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0-beta-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
      <version>${poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- http://books.evc-cit.info/odf_utils -->
      <groupId>com.catcode</groupId>
      <artifactId>odfutils</artifactId>
      <version>051129</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spell checking -->
    <!-- http://kenai.com/projects/jmyspell -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.dts</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmyspell-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-beta-2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Templates -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf</groupId>
      <artifactId>jodreports</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
      <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SIGAR -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hyperic</groupId>
      <artifactId>sigar</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.5.132</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GWT -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Only for development -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- GWT plugins -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gwt-log</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-log</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-incubator</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>gwt-vl.sourceforge.net</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-vl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0b-without-hibernate</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- KEA -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.openrdf.sesame</groupId>
      <artifactId>onejar</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gson: Java to Json conversion -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java CronTab Syntax Parser -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.kenai.crontab-parser</groupId>
      <artifactId>crontab-parser</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache CXF -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
          <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
      <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
      <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Plugin framework -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
      <artifactId>jspf</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Milton WebDAV -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ettrema</groupId>
      <artifactId>milton-api</artifactId>
      <version>${milton.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ettrema</groupId>
      <artifactId>milton-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${milton.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Java Bean to Java Bean mapper -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
      <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Language detection -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cybozu</groupId>
      <artifactId>langdetect</artifactId>
      <version>2011.11.28</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OWASP Java Encoders -->
    <!-- https://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-encoder/ -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
      <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Outlook Message -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.auxilii</groupId>
      <artifactId>msgparser</artifactId>
      <version>1.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- International Component for Unicode for Java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
      <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
      <version>51.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dropbox -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.dropbox.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropbox-client</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- OMR Tool -->
    <!-- http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aseth/udai/OMRProj/README.html -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ca.uwaterloo.a3seth</groupId>
      <artifactId>omr-tool</artifactId>
      <version>2007.07.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge</groupId>
      <artifactId>jiu</artifactId>
      <version>2007.07.01</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Video File manipulation -->
    <dependency>
   <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
   <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
   <version>5.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Recently i added the xuggle-xuggler:5.4 for video manipulation features. and upgraded most of the jar versions.Since then i am getting this error

Comment: You added different slf4j artifacts for version 1.7.5 and also projects which rely/pull in older versions of slf4j. Next to `slf4j-log4j12` and `jul-over-slf4j` add the `slf4j-api` (preferably in a dependencyManagement block saves you some excludes).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see which version of slf4j maven decides to give you. If it has picked the wrong version, you could use a dependency management section to specify which version you want.

If the output of dependency:tree shows the correct version (i.e. a version which does contain the method it can't find), then add `-verbose:class` as a jvm argument to see where it is loading that class from (e.g. if deploying in jboss it might be loading it from its internal logging jars instead of your slf4j jars).

Answer (score 9):

`dependency:tree`is a usefull tool that's true.

In addition, another way to fix it:

while using Eclipse IDE, use SHIFT + CTRL + T to open following type "`SLF4JLocationAwareLog`"

You should be able to find related library and so a potential conflict.

Switch to the dependency tree view of the `pom.xml` to know the exclusion to add.

In my case, was related to struts dependency `jcl104-over-slf4j`. I just exclude this one from the dependency:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when writing test cases while doing code refactoring in a Java 7 project. I fixed it  by replacing the old logging imports by slf4j loggers

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

in addition to it my pom dependencies looked like-

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-struts</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>velocity-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
            <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-gema-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-el</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-layout-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.19</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.gema.sso</groupId>
            <artifactId>gema-sso-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>struts</groupId>
                    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <filters>
        <filter>${basedir}/target/filter.properties</filter>
    </filters>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <!-- Safety -->
                            <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}" />
                            <tstamp>
                                <format property="build.time" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" />
                            </tstamp>
                            <tstamp>
                                <format property="build.nr" pattern="yyyyMMddhhmmss" />
                            </tstamp>
                            <echo file="${basedir}/target/filter.properties">
                                buildNr=${build.nr}
                                buildTime=${build.time}
                            </echo>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>fr.jcgay.maven.extension</groupId>
            <artifactId>unique-revision-maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in a Gradle project.

The answers given here were useful. I just had to solve it in a Gradle way.

Here is my solution:

```
configurations.all {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jcl104-over-slf4j'
}
```