# Cannot start Hive in terminal

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have installed and Configured Apache Hive-1.2.1 long ago. It worked fine. Recently I have installed Apache Spark-2.7.0 and started using its shells. Now when I want to work with Hive again, it didn't start. It's showing the following error:

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
 at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog.debug(SLF4JLocationAwareLog.java:133)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.logConfigLocation(LogUtils.java:147)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jDefault(LogUtils.java:128)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:77)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:637)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
```

I tried reinstalling Hive, but the same error follows. Is this error due to installing Spark? How can I run Hive normally again?

Comment: Looks like it may be something to do with a logging framework and version compatibilities.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519978/logging-framework-incompatibility

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are having a conflict with your *logging* library. This question could help you: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537459/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-slf4j-spi-locationawarelogger-log)